# How can I find a specific point in tsne plot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was using python to view tsne plot and want to find the index of a specific outlier. The tsne plot looks like this:

[image: image description]

Is there a way to find out the specific outlier index on the plot?

The code I used to generate the tsne plot:

```
tsne = manifold.TSNE(n_components=2, init= "pca",random_state=0)
ip1_tsne = tsne.fit_transform(feat)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print 'Processing tSNE complete'

ip1_tsne_display = ip1_tsne #[display_indices]
labels_display = labels #[display_indices]

classNames = ['Oribi', 'Nyala', 'Waterbuck', 'Elephant', 'Baboon', 'Porcupine', 'Impala', 'Genet', 'Bushbuck', 'Warthog']

print_classes = 10
cmap = plt.get_cmap('nipy_spectral')
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0, 1.0, print_classes))
test_colors = colors;
colors = (colors + np.ones(colors.shape))/2.0

f = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))

for label, color, className in zip(xrange(1,10), test_colors, classNames):
    plt.plot(ip1_tsne_display[labels_display == label, 0], ip1_tsne_display[labels_display == label, 1],
            'o', markersize=1.5, label=className, color=color)

plt.legend()
#plt.savefig('tsne.png')

plt.show()
f.savefig("tsne_fc7.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: You can use a picker on the points. See [this matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html) or in general the [event handling tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html).

Comment: A less elegant but quick solution would be to use something like this: `np.where((ip1_tsne[:, 0] > 20) & (ip1_tsne[:, 0] > 20))`